# Assign selected DB value as selected value in drop down JSP,Spring

Tags: spring, jsp

I have 2 tables. 
1) Prg (prgId, prgName).
2) RQ(rqId, prgId) which references Prg table ->prgId

I am showing on same page to add/modify for reference DB table(RQ). One column shows a drop down with values from parent table(Prg). This works fine. I am able to see all the values from Prg.prgName in the drop down.
I now have to improve the display and show on the selected in drop down to match with each record's with appropriate value.

JSP code:

```
<spring:bind path="programId"> 
    <td> <select name="${status.expression}" id = "programIdSelect" >
     <option value="-1" >---Selected---</option> 
     <c:forTokens var="currentHwId" items="${progamValueListParam}" delims=","> 
     <c:set var="temp" value=",${currentHwId}"></c:set> 
      <option value='<c:out value="${currentHwId}"/>' 
     <c:if test="${status.value == temp}">selected="selected"</c:if>> 
      <c:out value="${currentHwId}" /> </option> 
     </c:forTokens> </select> 
 </spring:bind>
```

progamValueListParam is populated in my controller class map.

I dont know if it is possible? need help.

Comment: What is above code?Is this what you tired or is it your answer?

Comment: that was my code so far. added for reference.

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.